# Formatting International Phone Numbers

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I have a project where I have an input for a phone number. Said phone number can be from any country. The user selected the country before entereing the phone number.

Is there a way to format the phone number as a user is typing it in WPF?

I was playing around with Google's library port for C# but to no avail ([click here](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/))

Thanks!

Comment: Substitute the word `project` for `homework`, then add examples, then explain how it fails, then someone might help :)

Comment: I wanted to know if someone has done this already. I have no code that is worth posting at this time. I wish this was homework...

Comment: You're asking for every possible phone number format in the world. No programmer in there right mind would attempt to cover every possible phone number format :) but you you are willing, which then suggests (to me) that it is homework! Think about it, or better still reread your question, in particular `Said phone number can be from any country`...that sounds like `every phone number format in the world`, doesn't it. I am helpful, but sometimes people need a slap in the face, I know I need every so often ;)...if it had already been done, then you would have found the answer already

Comment: So google has an API that I listed above... I was wondering if anyone else knew of another API...

Answer (score 1):

I can advise you to use two properties where in a property `HomeNumber` regular expression is used for formatting number input.

Example (closer to pseudocode):

```
public string Country
{
    get { return country; }
    set { country = value; }
}

public string HomeNumber
{
    get
    {
        if (homeNumber == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        if (country.Equals("USA"))
        {
            return Regex.Replace(homeNumber, @"(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})", "$1-$2-$3");
        }
        else if (country.Equals("Russia"))
        {
            return Regex.Replace(homeNumber, @"(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})", "$1-$2-$3");
        }
    }

    set
    {
        homeNumber = value;
    }
}
```

If countries to select a lot, to reduce the number of constructions `If`, I can advise to use the [`State`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) pattern.

`Advantages`

- simple solution
- does not require third-party libraries and projects

`Disadvantages`

- not a serious flaw, but the formatting of numbers is performed after the completion of printing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of international phone numbers is a mess for 3 reasons:

1) How to dial an international phone number depends on the country you are in. If your application is used in only one country, then this is not too bad. However, there might be several ways how to get an international connection, like dialing first 00 or simply +.

2) The country code for a phone number is particularly bad designed. Just some examples:

1339 USA
1340 Virgin Islands (Caribbean Islands)
1341 USA
1342 not used
1343 Canada

The US, Canada and some smaller places share 1 as country code and the next 3 digits decide, if it is US or Canada or ... There is no easy way to figure out the country, like the first xxx are Canada, the rest US.

Some countries have a 2 digits code, others 3 and 4.

3) Even within the same country, different regions can have different formats.

The simplest solution is probably:

1. use a different format for international and national numbers
2. use for all internation numers the format +ccc dddddddd, where cc is a variable (!) length country code and dddddddd the digits within the country
3. depending on how many digits are used for dddddddd, you can write them as ddd dd dd, dddd dddd and ddd ddd ddd.

Of course, you can complicate it further by formatting also the area code within a country. I can't help you with areas, but for the rest you can find the code on Github (too much to post here):
[github.com/PeterHuberSg/WpfWindowsLib/blob/master/WpfWindowsLib/PhoneTextBox.cs](https://github.com/PeterHuberSg/WpfWindowsLib/blob/master/WpfWindowsLib/PhoneTextBox.cs)

A detailed explanation of international phone numbers and the PhoneTextBox is on CodeProject:
[International Phone Number Validation Explained](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5264561/International-Phone-Number-Validation-Explained-in)